# How to assign a unique, ordered ID to a group of Java classes

Tags: java

Imagine the following scenario:

- I have a base class, let's say Fruit, with a number of subclasses like Apples, Oranges, etc.
- I also have a Person class with an inventory of various pieces of fruit. In this case, I'm only concerned with how many of each type of fruit the person has. It would not make sense to have each piece of Fruit be an object.
- I should also be able to remove a piece of fruit from the person's inventory, and then have an instantiated object.
- Fruit should have an intrinsic order that I can assign, so that it can be listed in a similar manner from multiple classes. Apples always go before Oranges, etc.

When I'm talking about fruit in the person's inventory, I want to be able to refer to it in a static way. As in `int n = person.getPiecesofFruit(Apple);`. But when I remove it from a person's inventory, I need the fruit to be an object, as in `Apple a = person.removeOne(Apple);`.

The obviously way to accomplish this seems to be to have each subclass of Fruit have a static ID field, so I could just write `int n = person.getPiecesofFruit(Apple.ID);`

This allows Person to simply contain an integer array where each Fruit's ID corresponds to an index where its count is located:

```
int[] fruitCounts = new int[Fruit.numberOfFruits()];

public int getPiecesOfFruit(int id) { return fruitCounts[id]; }
public int addFruit(int id, int count) { fruitCounts[id] += count; }
```

The problem is maintaining unique ordered ids (and ideally the ids should be consecutive). If I remove the Orange class, do I have to reassign every other Fruit's id? Or if I insert Pear between Apple and Orange, I have the same problem. I could use a linked-list approach and have `Apple.ID = Orange.ID + 1;` etc, which would maintain order, unless I messed up and made Orange and Pear both come after Apple by accident. Essentially, I'd like to combine the ordered list functionality of an Enum with the inheritance and OO-nature of a Class. Could someone tell me if there's a way this is typically accomplished.

I hope this question isn't too open-ended for S.O., but it's a problem I run into in a variety of scenarios, so I'm hoping there's a somewhat standardized solution.

Comment: use AtomicInteger http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html

Comment: "_It would not make sense to have each piece of Fruit be an object._" and `Apple a = person.removeOne(Apple);` sounds like a contradiction in your requirements.

Comment: As in, the person might have 1000 apples, which should not all be objects for memory reasons. When I remove one, I'd like to be able to instantiate a new apple, but not until I need it.

Comment: @thomas88wp: How would you add one?

Comment: @jlordo see my edits above. Person's backend would just be a simple int array. It's the auto-incrementing ID that's getting me.

Comment: Sounds like an X-Y problem. As it is I don't understand what the use case is here. Do these fruits have state? It doesn't sound like it, since you only want to store the count. If that's the case, what good is it to remove a fruit and turn it into an object?

Comment: @TomG, let's say the fruits don't have state, so each Apple would be the same, but Apples and Oranges would not. In order to call something like fruit.getName(), I'd need an object.

Comment: @thomas88wp: you can _easily_ do that with an `enum`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds to me like you really need a `Fruit` enum, with values `APPLE`, `ORANGE`, `PEAR`. Enums in Java are full-fledged classes; they can have fields and methods. This way, you can store the count in each fruit type, with add() and subtract() methods. Each time you call `person.add(Fruit f)`, inside that method you would invoke `f.add()`, and each time you call `person.remove(Fruit f)`, you would invoke `f.subtract()`.

This also lets you entirely sidestep the ordering problem -- enums have a very simply defined ordering based on their declaration.

Comment: Careful with this...  enums can have fields, true, but each element is effectively a singleton.  So if you call `Fruit.APPLE.add()` or `Fruit.APPLE.subtract()`, you'll be changing the *universal* count of that Apples, not the count that this `Person` has.

Comment: @sharakan: yes, Tom G got that mixed up, but anyway: `enum Fruit` is the way to go to solve OPs problem. +1 for that.

Comment: Yeah, Enum was my first though, but the problem is you lose inheritance. I can't have Apple override Fruit's methods.

Comment: @thomas88wp yes, you can... just put abstract methods on the enum level, and override them for the elements: eg, getColor, getSize...

Comment: @sharakan Ah, I see, you're right. Enums can't extend others, but Apple could override Fruit's methods. I don't suppose there's any way to move Apple to a separate file from Fruit though... As more Fruit are added that gets a little nasty. I was thinking I might just have both an Enum and a Class, with a reference from one to the other. Enum maintains the order and Class holds the functionality.

Comment: @TomG I probably could have saved some time by asking "any better way to do this than enums" but you essentially answered the question, so I'll mark it. Thanks everyone for the input - sorry it wasn't the most straightforward question.